# Jquery refresh page, then do something

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to use Jquery or JavaScript to execute a command after page refresh? 
Something like this, exept, my code doesnt work.

```
<script>
$('#some-button').click(function() {
   location.reload();
   $('#another-button').trigger("click");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Yes. Possible**

with help of [haschange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange)

1. Update some hash value to the url `onClick`
2. Then match the [hasvalue](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp) while on haschange event

**Code**

```
<script>
window.addEventListener("hashchange", hasChanger, false);

function hasChanger(){
  var key = window.location.hash
  if(key == '#trigger'){
     $('#another-button').trigger("click");
  }
}

$('#some-button').click(function() {
   window.location.href = window.location.href+'#trigger'
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easily can do with Navigation Timing api.

```
checkReloadedPage(){
      if (window.performance) {
        console.info("window.performance working");
      }
      if (performance.navigation.type == 1) {
       // mean page is reloaded
        return 1;
      } else {
        //mean page is not reloaded
        return 2;
      }
    }
```

Navigation timing api: https://www.w3.org/TR/navigation-timing/

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using localstorage trick.

```
 <script>
    $('#some-button').click(function() {
       // Save on local storage
       localStorage.setItem("myfunction", "dosomething");
       location.reload();

    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
        // Retrieve stored data
        if(localStorage.getItem("myfunction")=="dosomething")
        {
           //remove saved data
           localStorage.removeItem("myfunction");
           //do your stuff here
           $('#another-button').trigger("click");
         }
     });
    </script>
```

By the way it is not recommended to do that in such a way to do something after reloading the page.

If you wanna do such like things you can also use server side sessions to store data for sharing between different pages pages.
Using AJAX which is the far best approach than this you can easily do that in javascript or jquery.

```
$.post('pageAdress',{'key':'value'},function(result){
    //do youe stuff here
});
```

this function require 3 parameters

1. Pages address to be called
2. pass data through post method if you want
3. callback function

You can implement that in your way based on your requirements which contents you want to reload.
This can perform your code without page reloading